# Support of encoding/Decoding video files in Android

Tags: android, audio, video, video-encoding, decoding

I want to know the list of supported audio/video formats by Android 2.2, 2.3 and 3,4. I also want to know which Android versions support video encoding and decoding. I went through [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), but I am not getting clear idea about encoding and decoding.

Answer from anyone is highly appreciable.

Comment: I don't know how to make it clearer than the docs. What is missing according to you?

Comment: While Considering Encoder/Decoder coloumns in the table of mentioned link, for some of them mentioned like 4.1+, for some of them used dots(.) ,and some of them left blank... . i didn't understand this formats. and one more thing,no where menctioned 2.2,so here 2.2 wont support any encoding or decoding.?

Answer (score 1):

**empty** means 'not supported' 
**dot** means 'supported' 
**in parenthesis**: (supported starting from 'android version')

where an ancoder/decor is supported without specifying a 'starting version' , simply means: supported from the first released version of Android